# Python Kivy: changing the value of min_state_time attribute does not change button's behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

In my Kivy app I need a `Button` which will change current screen of the Screen Manager. However, I want to make sure that the user will not press it accidently. So, I set `on_release()` event and according to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html). I should be able to set the attribute `min_state_time` (which defaults to 0.035 sec.), which is supposed to enable to initiate `on_release()` event only after the button is in 'down' state for a specified period of time (here 2 sec).

This is the `class` of the `Button`:

```
class EscapeButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EscapeButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # I'm changing min_state_time:
        self.min_state_time = 2.0
    def on_press(self):
        self.background_color = (1,1,1,0.5)
    def on_release(self):
        self.background_color = (0,0,0,0)
```

This is the same `class` in `kv` file

```
<EscapeButton>:
    #min_state_time: 2.0 - I tried to set it like this but it didn't work
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    font_size: '16sp'
    color: (1,1,1,0.5)
```

The instance of the `Button` in `kv`:

```
EscapeButton:
    #min_state_time: 2.0 - I also tried here
    text:'X'
    on_release: root.escape_test()
```

And the function in `main.py`:

```
    def escape_test(self):
        sm.current = 'settings'
```

So, the problem is that although `min_state_time`'s value changes (I checked that), it doesn't change anything in button's behavior because `on_release()` is fired regardless of that value (i.e. instantly). Does anyone know how this should work?

Comment: The `min_state_time` affects how long the `Button` stays in the `down` state. It has no effect on when `on_press` or `on_release` events happen.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I must have misunderstood. Just thought it would spare a few lines of code. I used kivy.clock instead.